# Why does Port Forwarding stop working every new day without me doing anything?

Tags: router, ftp, port-forwarding

I successfully set up a FTP server on my computer with FileZilla Server. It works perfectly in the Local Network (I set up a static IP address, 192.168.2.20) and also other people can reach it through the internet (I did not buy any domain or public static IP address, so I just message my address to the people that want access). Therefore I added a Port Forwarding Rule to my router settings. Everything works fine. People can access, upload, download, etc.
But every new day it stops working. I can still access the FTP Server in the Local Network but other people can not access it through the internet (with the new correct address I sent them). Nothing has been changed but it just stops working for people that are not in the Local Network.
After I remove the Forwarding Rule and add it again it works again. Unfortunately I cannot do these steps every day. Am I missing some setting or is it my Router?
Router: KPN Experia Box H220N (2013)

Comment: Sounds like your ISP is resetting the connection & IP address overnight. The forwarding rule is possibly remembering the old address as 'hard-coded' & can't handle the new one until it's replaced with current data. I'd take a guess you need either a smarter router or a smarter ISP. My WAN address has only changed twice in 20 years & I don't pay extra for mine either, it's just how my ISP deal with it.

Comment: When you remove the port-forwarding rule and add it again, is the IP of your computer the same as before?

Comment: @harrymc Yes it is.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you for the fast reply!